# Need opinions regarding the premises of a probability question

Tags: probability

I was asked this question in an interview, and did not initially answer correctly though I still think my interpretation may have been the correct one. The question was:

There are two delivery trucks, A and B. A makes deliveries between 8am and 10am, and B makes deliveries between 9am and 11am. The deliveries are uniformly distributed for both. What is the probability that any given delivery from B will take place before any given delivery from A?

Their answer, which with prodding I eventually arrived at as well, is 1/8. However, it seems to me that IF I remember the precise statement of the question correctly, the true answer is impossible to determine without knowing the relative delivery rates for each truck.

If you assume (and perhaps they did state) that the trucks deliver at the same rate, then it seems to me that the correct answer is 1/4 because the question is asking about the ratio of B's deliveries before A to B's total deliveries, not to ALL deliveries by both vehicles.

What do you think, and where am I going wrong if I am? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The phrasing is certainly ambiguous.  If $A$ only has one delivery to make and $B$ has millions, then I'd say the answer was $\frac 12$ since $A's$ sole delivery will occur before $9$ with probability $\frac 12$ but $B$ will surely start delivery right at the stroke of $9$.  Of course, other assumptions regarding the deliveries will give different answers.

Comment: suppose each,  A and B ,only have one deliver.Then 0.5 A delivers between 9 am and 10 am and B aswell. And now consider that both have  equal probability to deliver first, i.e. 0.5 Thus we get $ 0.5^3=\frac 18$

Comment: I suspect that they don't mean "before **all** deliveries from A", but rather "before **any given** delivery from A".  The given delivery from A is assumed to be uniformly distributed in the interval $[8,10]$, the given delivery from B is assumed to be uniformly distributed in the interval $[9,11]$, and the two are assumed to be independent.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Precisely, and you are right that I meant to type in the initial question "before any given delivery from A". But thinking more about it, I think they actually said "What is the probability that a delivery from B takes place before a delivery from A?", so isn't it 1/4 since it's only referring (in my mind) to the packages on B's truck, and if there were 100 then 25 of them (half of those in the overlap window) arrived before A. I really do not do well with verbally conveyed information, especially when a slight difference in phrasing changes the result :(

Comment: And does it no matter at all that these packages are not going to the same places? What does it mean to say that a package from B arrived before a package from A? Doesn't the use of the word "before" imply that the packages from A and B had the same destination, which is very unlikely? Maybe the real answer is zero, unless this is a very dumb package service sending multiple trucks to the same place on the same day.

Comment: I think the only sensible interpretation is that A and B are both making deliveries (to the same location) at a rate of one per day. Think of a pizza parlor which receives deliveries of paper napkins and pizza dough every Monday; on a given Monday, what is the probability the pizza dough arrives before the napkins? I also do not understand your complaints about the locations not being specified; A and B do not need to be going to the same place to talk about whether A's delivery arrived before B's delivery. There are two times for each delivery, one is before the other.

Comment: In an interview, what matters is not so much whether you get the right answer, but how you process the information you're given.  In particular, it's important to ask the interviewer for clarification when there are ambiguities in the question.

Answer (score 1):

"What is the probability that a delivery from B takes place before a delivery from A?" I take this to mean a single random delivery by B being before a single random delivery by A. As an interview question, the interviewer is probably more interested in your analysis of the question rather than you getting the right answer.

My quick and dirty response would be:

The probability of a single A delivery between $9$ am and $10$ am is $0.5$ (the only interval where B can be before A).

The probability of a single B delivery before the A will range from $0.5\cdot 0$ (A at $9$ am) to $0.5\cdot 0.5$ (A at $10$ am) which is $0$ to $0.25$. Because of the linearity in changing probability over time, the overall probability is:

$P = \frac{0 + 0.25}{2} = 0.125$